# xlPastevalues is giving me an object defined error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub foo()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("inbd")
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = Sheets("test")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A1:N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, 
Criteria1:=Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 26).Value
    ws.Range("f2:f" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("C6")
DestinationRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wsDestination.Range("C" & DestinationRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ws.Range("A1:N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1




End Sub
```

Good evening, Paste values part is giving me an object defined error and I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a test to ensure there are visible cells to copy from:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(ws.Range("A1:N" & LastRow),Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 26).Value) > 0
```

. A test that you have more than one cell for your filter

```
If LastRow > 1
```

and you also have already pasted with this line:

```
ws.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("C6")
```

You pasted to C6 and now have an empty clipboard so cannot paste again.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
ws.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
DestinationRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
wsDestination.Range("C" & DestinationRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already pasted the copied cells into the inbd sheet C6.

Your code does not make much sense. You determine the last row of data before you filter, you copy and paste, then you paste again. I suggest you first filter, then determine the last row in both sheets, then do the copy and paste special right after one another without the wrong paste to C6 step.